# cannot add right bar button item to navigation item

Tags: ipad, ios5

I would like to implement a method to add a done bottom to the right of the title navigation bar as so as some one starts entering text in a UITextView but for some reason nothing happens. The method gets called but does not add the button:

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{  
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton;
    [doneButton setTarget:self];
    [doneButton setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone];
    [doneButton setAction:@selector(keyboardDone:)];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:doneButton animated:YES];           
}
```

Am I doing something really basic wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alloc and init a UIBarButton item before it's ready for use. All you did was declare that "doneButton" was a UIBarButtonItem but you never properly set it up for use.